# Stay on the same div after clicking submit - php - js

Tags: javascript, php, html

Javascript code:

```
    var formS = document.getElementById('formS');
    var formC = document.getElementById('formC');

    formS.addEventListener('click',function(){

              formC.scrollIntoView();

          });
```

html - php code

```
<div id="formC">
            <h1>Φόρμα Επικοινωνίας</h1>
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
<form id="form0" method="post">

              <div class="requiredM00">
                  <p style="color:red"><?php echo $requiredMessage;?></p><p style="color: rgb(64, 180, 249)"><?php echo $completeMessage;?></p>
              </div>
              <label for="name">Όνομα <span class="error" style="color:red">*<?php echo $nameErr;?></span></label>
              <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">

              <label for="email">Email <span class="error" style="color:red">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span></label>
              <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">

              <label for="phone">Τηλέφωνο <span class="error" style="color:blue"> <?php echo $phoneErr;?></span></label>
              <input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone;?>">

              <label for="subject">Μήνυμα <span class="error" style="color:red">*<?php echo $subjectErr;?></span></label>
              <textarea id="subject" name="subject" style="height:200px"    ><?php echo $subject; ?></textarea>
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg bat" id="formS" value="Αποστολή">

            </form>
</div>
```

When I change type from submit to button the result is that i want, but php didn't work.
I want remain in form and php code run too.

Thank you.

Comment: A post request will reload your page. Use AJAX

Comment: AJAX tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: I want specific help with code for my case study. Thanks